# How to match all of elements of array in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table, and list of indexes, I want google sheets return a list of matched value.Something like this, but i doesn't work in this case. Can you help me the correct formula that it work on Google Sheet.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(A2:B4,N(IF(1,D2))))
```

[image: google sheet table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a formula in one cell (no need to copy it down):

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", FALSE, ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",,", FALSE, $D$2:$D$5), ",", TRUE, FALSE), $A$2:$B$4, 2, 0)))), ",,", FALSE, FALSE))
```

[image]

What exactly this formula does, going **from the inside out** (from `TEXTJOIN(",,", ...` to `TRANSPOSE(...`):

1. First `TEXTJOIN` joins the *Condition* range (`D2:D4`, or more if needed) in one string.

   - `",,"` (the exact string of two commas) is used as the delimiter: a comma is allowed (you already use it, means there should not be commas in column `A2:A4`) and two commas can be distinguished from only one.
   - Empty strings (cells in that case) are not to be excluded so the result will be aligned with the original data.
2. First `SPLIT` gives a list of keys to be found in `A2:A4`.

   - Empty strings are preserved, so it is possible to assemble all of this back together later using `",,"`. Empty strings are now the delimiters.
3. `VLOOKUP` replaces the keys (`A2:A4`) by the values (`B2:B4`)
4. `IFNA` is needed so `VLOOKUP` won't choke on an empty string passed as a key. An empty string will remain an empty string.
5. `ARRAYFORMULA` is effectively needed for passing a range of keys (the one from the step 2) to `VLOOKUP` instead of just one key.
6. Second `TEXTJOIN` assembles all those values back together.

   - Empty strings are preserved as they are the delimiters between two *Conditions*.
   - Because of the empty strings results for each row will be separated with `",,"` (two commas).
7. Second `SPLIT` is used to separate the results for each row.

   - Empty strings are preserved for alignment with the original data.
8. `TRANSPOSE` just rotates the result into a column.

---

The same in a readable form (it is valid to type a formula like this):

```
=TRANSPOSE(
  SPLIT(
    TEXTJOIN(
      ",",
      FALSE,
      ARRAYFORMULA(
        IFNA(
          VLOOKUP(
            SPLIT(
              TEXTJOIN(
                ",,",
                FALSE,
                $D$2:$D$4
              ),
              ",",
              TRUE,
              FALSE
            ),
            $A$2:$B$4,
            2,
            0
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    ",,",
    FALSE,
    FALSE
  )
)
```

Comment: The best solution for this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in `E2` and copy it down

```
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(D2, ","), $A$2:$B$4, 2, 0)))
```

[image]